# How to set path of Auto IT in python

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I want to automate file upload through auto it library using selenium with python but I am getting the following error on executing the code:

```sh
from .autoit import options, properties, commands
  File "C:\Users\garima.madaan\PycharmProjects\TestPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\autoit\autoit.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise IOError("Cannot load AutoItX from path: %s" % dll_path)
OSError: Cannot load AutoItX from path: C:\Users\garima.madaan\PycharmProjects\TestPythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\autoit\lib\AutoItX3.dll

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is the code which I have written:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import autoit
import time

class Upload():

    def test(self):
        baseurl = 'https://easyupload.io/'
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(baseurl)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,300);")
        time.sleep(5)

        #click on click here to drop files
        element1= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='upload-section']/form/div/button")
        element1.click()
        time.sleep(5)

        #select a file using autoit
        autoit.win_wait_active("Open")
        driver.close()

a= Upload()
a.test()
```

Comment: Why don't you use `input[type='file']` ? I don't think AutoIT is required here

Comment: I have used that but I want to upload file through Auto it....Any suggestions on that

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Autoit example using https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=153520

I hope someone finds this useful.

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <TabConstants.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <WinAPIGdi.au3>
#include <WinAPIGdiDC.au3>
#include <WinAPIHObj.au3>
#include <WinAPISysWin.au3>
#include <AD.au3>
#include <Array.au3>
#include "UIAWrappers.au3"
#include <FileConstants.au3>
#include <WinAPIFiles.au3>
#include <GuiListBox.au3>
#include <Word.au3>
#include <File.au3>
#include <Excel.au3>


Opt("WinWaitDelay", 150)
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 2)
Opt("WinDetectHiddenText", 1)
Opt("MouseCoordMode", 2)
Opt("SendKeyDelay", 10)
Opt("GUIResizeMode", 1)
HotKeySet("^!x", "MyExit")

Global  $Web, $hWnd

$Web = "https://easyupload.io/"

ShellExecute("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", "--new-window --force-renderer-accessibility " & $Web, "", "")
WinWait("Easyupload.io - Upload files for free and transfer big files easily. - Google Chrome", "", 8)
$hWnd = WinGetHandle("Easyupload.io - Upload files for free and transfer big files easily. - Google Chrome")
WinActivate($hWnd)
WinSetState($hWnd, "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
;Sleep(7000); Give time for the webpage to load (out of country)
Local $oP6=_UIA_getObjectByFindAll($UIA_oDesktop, "Title:=Easyupload.io - Upload files for free and transfer big files easily. - Google Chrome;controltype:=UIA_PaneControlTypeId;class:=Chrome_WidgetWin_1", $treescope_children)
_UIA_Action($oP6,"setfocus")
Local $oP5=_UIA_getObjectByFindAll($oP6, "Title:=Easyupload.io - Upload files for free and transfer big files easily.;controltype:=UIA_DocumentControlTypeId;class:=Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND", $treescope_children)
_UIA_Action($oP5,"setfocus")

;~ First find the object in the parent before you can do something
Local $oUIElement=_UIA_getObjectByFindAll("(Max25files,10GBperfile).mainwindow", "title:=(Max 25 files, 10 GB per file);ControlType:=UIA_TextControlTypeId", $treescope_subtree)
Local $oUIElement=_UIA_getObjectByFindAll($oP5, "title:=(Max 25 files, 10 GB per file);ControlType:=UIA_TextControlTypeId", $treescope_subtree)
_UIA_Action($oUIElement, "setfocus")
_UIA_Action($oUIElement, "highlight")
_UIA_Action($oUIElement, "activate")
_UIA_Action($oUIElement, "leftclick")


Func MyExit()
    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>MyExit
```